# Django - Custom header to application/x-zip-compressed HttpResponse

Tags: django, httpresponse

I have a Django App which contains a view that returns a `.zip` file using `HttpResponse`

```
resp = HttpResponse(s.getvalue(), content_type="application/x-zip-compressed")
resp['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % zip_filename

return resp
```

The `.zip` is created inside the view where I also calculate its `checksum`.

On the client-side I use a `requests.get()` to get the `zip` file.

How can I send the checksum in the same `HttpResponse` along with the `zip`.

I tried adding the checksum to the header by

```
resp['hash-key'] = sha_checksum
```

but on the client `requests.headers['hash-key']` seems to be `None`

How can I do this?

---

### Edit:

As it seems my problem is located in the calculation of the hash which results in `None`.

The strange thing is that the same function is used on the client-side and works fine, but I guess this is another question.

Comment: Setting `resp['hash-key']` looks like the correct response. Is the header in the response (but empty) or not in the response at all?

Comment: @Alasdair It is in the response but with None as value

Comment: Strange. Just to double check, you're sure that `sha_checksum` is not `None` before you assign it?

Comment: @Alasdair It's the same function that I use on the client side and it works, I can post its code so you can check

Comment: I don't think showing the code would help, I just wanted to check that you have printed the value before you assign it, to check that you are not doing `resp['hash-key'] = None`.

Comment: @Alasdair Actually, you were right. When opening the file in order to get the hash, a `.` preceding caused the open to fail, hence giving `None`. I was sure that it worked as a method, and I didn't check the value before the assignment to `resp['hash-key']`. I feel dumb now

Comment: Glad you found the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `hash-key` is in the response, it sounds like this line is working.

```
resp['hash-key'] = sha_checksum
```

Try printing the value of `sha_checksum` before you assign it, to make sure it is not `None`.